# Maintaining Power Query connections for Excel workbook when it's run through Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, powerquery

I have a couple of large data frames that I am pasting into a pre-formulated Excel template workbook. The template is set up to have a couple of power query connections between tables in different tabs, which get populated by the data frames from Python.

After the template is passed through a Python code and the data frames pasted into them and saved, the workbook no longer has the power query connections.

Is there a good way to maintain power query connections for Excel files that run through Python?

Pasting below the part of the code that pulls in the template and the part in which it is saved:

```
copy_to_wb = load_workbook(filename=r'C:\test\Template.xlsx', data_only=False)
diff_tab = copy_to_wb['Between-File Inconsistencies']
first_tab = copy_to_wb['First']
second_tab = copy_to_wb['Second']

copy_to_wb.save(root.save_location)
messagebox.showinfo('Complete message','Program ran successfully! Check for your new file.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the dataframes loaded into Excel are formatted as Table in Excel and that these Tables are connected into the existing Power Query connections. To convert dataframes to Table, highlight the dataset and press Ctrl + T to create a Table. Then, from Ribbon tab, select Data > Get Data From Table/Range. The power query connections has to be referencing the Table you just created in Excel for it to work.